# Cannot drag files with OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

Normally to drag I

- Click on item to drag
- Hold down with one finger
- Then do dragging motion with another finger

Now when I click on an item a popup shows up showing a window into the content of the file. So now I cannot move a file from one folder to another. Does anyone know the fix for this issue?

If I enable three-finger dragging then it takes away my ability to use three-fingers to slide between screens.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] or [apple.se] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] has more information regarding the types of question that are appropriate here. Good luck.

Comment: Can someone with the power to do so please move this question to a more appropriate site? It has the perfect answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you've got a Mac with a force-sensitive trackpad and you're pushing hard enough to trigger Quick Look.  Don't push as hard to get a regular click; you can disable "Force Click and haptic feedback" in Trackpad System Preferences.

Comment: Thank you. This feature is very frustrating :(